# Avoid $compile:multidir

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my problem.
I created 2 directives (`ngResizable` and `ngMovable`) and tried to add them to my element.

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BaseController as baseCtrl">
    <div id="params">
        <div>Width: <input type="number" ng-model="baseCtrl.model.sizes[0]"/></div>
        <div>Height: <input type="number" ng-model="baseCtrl.model.sizes[1]"/></div>
        <div>Pos X: <input type="number" ng-model="baseCtrl.model.position[0]"/></div>
        <div>Pos Y: <input type="number" ng-model="baseCtrl.model.position[1]"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="element"
             ng-style="{
                 left:   baseCtrl.model.position[0],
                 top:    baseCtrl.model.position[1],
                 width:  baseCtrl.model.sizes[0],
                 height: baseCtrl.model.sizes[1]
             }"
             ng-resizable="baseCtrl.model.sizes"
             ng-movable="baseCtrl.model.position">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
(function(angular){
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app", [])
        .controller("BaseController", function(){
            this.model = {
                sizes: [200, 100],
                position: [0, 0]
            }
        })
        .directive("ngResizable", function(){
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {
                    sizes: "=ngResizable"
                },
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    element.resizable({
                        handlers: "s,e",
                        resize: function(){
                            scope.sizes[0] = parseInt(element.width());
                            scope.sizes[1] = parseInt(element.height());
                            scope.$apply();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }   
        })
        .directive("ngMovable", function(){
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {
                    position: "=ngMovable"
                },
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    element.draggable({
                        drag: function(event) {
                            var pos = element.position();
                            scope.position[0] = pos.left;
                            scope.position[1] = pos.top;
                            scope.$apply();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }   
        })
})(angular)
```

I also binded some parameters (`sizes` and `position`) from controller to the element and inputs and wrote functions to manipulate them from directives.
It works fine if only one directive is in use but when I used both of them $compile:multidir error occurred.
Is it possible to avoid this error?

Here is jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gju8frsw

And here is almost warking demo with one directive: http://jsfiddle.net/gju8frsw/1/

Comment: You need to only have one isolate scope per element. This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221245/can-multiple-directives-for-one-element-share-an-isolated-scope

Comment: @Rorschach120, those are clearly independent directives, so the `require` approach needlessly couples them together. `require` is better suited when directives are always or often used together (`ngModel` and validators, or `ngModel` and `form`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiple directives creating their own isolate and/or child scopes (both could require `scope: true`, though) is not allowed, which is unfortunate, if only because with `scope: {}` binding to attributes is so effortless.

But, you could still achieve the same result by doing a bit more manual work and using the `$parse` service. Here's an illustrative example of how to achieve two-way binding:

```
.directive("foo", function($parse){
  return {
    restrict: "A", 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var fooGetFn = $parse(attrs.foo),
          fooSetFn = fooGetFn.assign;

      var foo0 = fooGetFn(scope); // get the current value of foo expression

      // watch for changes in foo expression
      scope.$watch(
        function(){ return fooGetFn(scope); },
        function fooWatchAction(newVal, oldVal){
          // do whatever needed
        });

      // set value to foo expression, if it's assignable
      if (fooSetFn) fooSetFn(scope, "abc");     
    }
  }
});
```

You could do the same with `bar` and have them working side-by-side:

```
<div foo="vm.p1" bar="vm.p2">
```

In your specific case, you don't even need to assign the value back since you are only assigning to properties of the bound object (which you only need to get), so it is simpler.

Here's your forked **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7an9dc9o/)** that works.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you.