# Using custom directive date formatter on angular-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

Can some one with angular expertise help me on this one. I have a custom directive that modifies the date from mmddyyyy format to mm/dd/yyyy format. It works fine in simple models.

```
app.directive('bsDateFormatter', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope : false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            var dateCheckRegex=new RegExp(/\d{8}/);

            var dateFormatter = function(dateValue) {
                if(dateValue == undefined){
                    dateValue = '';
                }
                var dateFormatted = dateValue;

                if (dateValue.length==8 && dateCheckRegex.test(dateValue)){
                        var mm=dateValue.substr(0,2);
                        var dd=dateValue.substr(2,2);
                        var yy=dateValue.substr(-4);
                        dateFormatted = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yy;
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yy);
                        modelCtrl.$render();
                }

                return dateFormatted;
            };
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(dateFormatter);
            dateFormatter(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
        }
    };
});
```

The problem comes when I use the same directive in angular-bootstrap datepicker-popup. The contents do not get reformatted.

EDIT:
here is the plunker for what I am trying to achieve.
https://plnkr.co/edit/xbu308o4GEBST0yrom19?p=preview
The custom directives work on the input text box. Does not work with the input box with the datepicker-popup directive.

Comment: the datepicker-popup is a directive with an isolated scope. Are we allowed to use multiple directive in the same element?

Comment: I think there is an issue with isolated scope. Can't answer you, but try to see this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/23221245/can-multiple-directives-for-one-element-share-an-isolated-scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221245/can-multiple-directives-for-one-element-share-an-isolated-scope)

Comment: @doroshko I don't think that I am allowed to edit the third party directives at my work. But I got a better understanding on the issue so thanks for that.